# dispatch_once in ShareKit causing crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, sharekit, sigabrt

I was using ShareKit for a p long time, without downloading last updates from its repository. 
Now i need some of its new features, so i've pulled all last commits and tried to run my app with new ShareKit without making any changes to my code (except some small changes in includes).

App compiles without errors but when i try to execute usual Facebook sharing code - it crashes without any useful error description.

old code i want to get to work

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:sk::game_services::get_app_store_url()]];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:message] contentType:SHKURLContentTypeWebpage];

[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

and according to updated ShareKit demo app and its documentation - this code should still work.
but it doesn't

it horribly crashes in **currentIndicator** method of **SHKActivityIndicator** inside macro **DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE_USING_BLOCK** that contains **dispatch_once** call.

debugger just says "SIGABRT" and thats all.

i don't know what to do.

Comment: I found what was wrong: window property of my AppController was private and ShareKit code couldn't get access to it.

Comment: I have a similar crash - are you able to explain what you did to fix this?

Comment: I have just added `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;` to my AppController class, because formerly `UIWindow *window` was just a private member of it and ShareKit could not get acces to window.

Comment: Thanks - turns out it was just a name issue for me too. =D